# ¿Es posible establecer el alto de un campo de texto al alto de la sección en Crystal Reports?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

Estoy buscando la forma de establecer el alto de un campo al alto de la sección que lo contiene:

[image: Imagen de Crystal reports]

En la derecha, hay un campo de texto y este puede crecer y cuando lo hace, el alto de la sección también aumenta, pero el texto de la izquierda permanece en esa posición y necesito posicionarlo a la mitad del alto de la sección.

¿Es posible hacer eso?

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un [example], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas qué preguntas son mal vistas, [help].

Comment: Te agradezco la sugerencia @AndresGardiol, los voy a leer 